# Java - How to pass in type Class<A<B>> to method

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I have one method, say `getHystrixClass(Class<A<B>> clazz)`. It requires input type of `Class<A<B>>` to pass in. How to do that? I have tried a few methods, but all of them failed at compilation time which are shown below with their corresponding error messages.

#### First trial

Put in class `A`

```
getHystrixClass(A.class)
```

ERROR MESSAGE : The method `getHystrixClass(Class<A<B>>)` in the type `IHystrixProvider<A<B>>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Class<A>)`

#### Second trial

Put in class `B`

```
getHystrixClass(B.class)
```

ERROR MESSAGE : The method `getHystrixClass(Class<A<B>>)` in the type `IHystrixProvider<A<B>>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Class<B>)`

#### Third trial

Put in class `A<B>`

```
getHystrixClass(A<B>.class)
```

ERROR MESSAGE : `A` cannot be resolved to a variable

#### Fourth trial

Create a dummy object and get class form it.

```
A<B> dummy = new A<B>();
getHystrixClass(dummy.getClass())
```

ERROR MESSAGE : The method `getHystrixClass(Class<A<B>>)` in the type `IHystrixProvider<A<B>>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Class<capture#1-of ? extends A>)`

Any hint? Sorry for my bad English.

---

Edit:

Hi, @GhostCat

The interface is look something like below

```
// Define by my team lead
public interface IHystrixProvider<T extends HystrixCommand, Rq> {
    T getHystrixClass(Class<T> hystrixCommand);
}

/**
* @param <R> the return type
*/
public abstract class HystrixCommand<R> extends ... {
    ...
}
```

Code of HystrixCommand.java is public repository which can get from [GitHub](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.java)

Comment: you can remove c & C class in your example for more clearly and what is you getHystrixClass function param definition?

Comment: I don't think you can thanks to type erasure.  You'd have to give it two arguments; A.class and B.class.

Comment: @yelliver, edited. Thank for suggestions. :)

Comment: @user2478398, I can't change the method to pass in two arguments. The method is already fix by my team lead. :(

Comment: Could you please give the full content of that method? For example the interface it is defined in? You see, `Class<A<B>>` just doesnt make much sense in the first place. And maybe, consider talking to your **team lead** when you have problems with his code.

Comment: `IHystrixProvider<T extends HystrixCommand, Rq>` did you mean `IHystrixProvider<T extends HystrixCommand, R>`? Have you tried with `IHystrixProvider<T extends HystrixCommand<R>, R>`?

Comment: @Onheiron Nope, I don't have the right to change the method. However, `HystrixCommand` give warning because it is a raw type.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `Class<A<B>>` using a (unchecked) cast - this is necessary because there is no `Class` object that represents the generic type `A<B>`, only one for the raw type `A`.

```
getHystrixClass((Class<A<B>>) (Class) A.class)
```

This will perform casts in the following order:

```
Class<A> (type of A.class) -> Class -> Class<A<B>>
```

Note that you first need the cast to raw `Class` in order to avoid an `incompatible cast` warning. Both casts also have zero runtime overhead, because the raw type (`Class`) stays the same, only the type arguments change.